# how to integrate play framework with scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, integrate, scala-ide

How to integrate play framework with scala IDE ?
I have already created project with command 
**sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8** as suggested on official site https://www.playframework.com/getting-started and then imported project to scala IDE .
Which file in project has to run ? and how to run it in IDE.
[I can not open index.scala.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZqng.png)
[image]

Comment: open build.sbt and then click on open as project, for play there should be depencency or some plugin.

Comment: There is no option ,open as project. Yes Scala IDE has play framework feature but I want to know how to run that project in scala IDE.

Comment: What do you mean by play framework feature ? Do you mean `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.2")` and `sbt eclipse` command ? How did you import the project to Scala IDE? Anyway, the short answer to your questions is: You run play project from command line and not from Eclipse. The command line is: `sbt run`

Comment: then why we integrate play framework project with eclipse ?

Comment: You seem to be having multiple issues with your Scala IDE. I downloaded fresh Scala IDE from http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html, I added SBT plugin and ran `sbt eclipse` according to https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/IDE. And I imported the generated project into my workspace. All looks good. https://imgur.com/a/U4MV9yx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a answer whenever you create project through command **play new newApp**.

Then go to that project folder(cd newApp) and add eclipse dependency by command **play eclipse** .

then import that project into Scala IDE.